# How to register my Visual Studio Addin for debugger events?

Tags: debugging, events, build, visual-studio-2013, add-in

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2013 addin (in C#), and I want to register for an event that notify me when the user builds his project. How do I do that? 
There's _dispBuildEvents_OnBuildBeginEventHandler OnBuildBegin , how do I register to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
events = DTE.Events
buildEvents = events.BuildEvents
buildEvents.OnBuildBegin += MyHandler;

private EnvDTE.Events events;
private EnvDTE.BuildEvents buildEvents;
```

Comment: A little explanation or a few comments in the code would help the OP understand the answer.

Comment: Thanks!
I had some COM exceptions with a similar solution, so eventually I used EnvDte's Debugger Events.